# Uniform convergance for $f_n(x)=x^n-x^{2n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

the function $f_n(x)=x^n-x^{2n}$ converge to $f(x)=0$ in $(-1,1]$. Intuativly the function does not converge uniformally in (-1,1]. How can I prove it?
I tried using the definition $\lim \limits_{n\to\infty}\sup \limits_{ x\in (-1,1]}|f_n(x)-f(x)|$ function is continial fractional on $[-1,1]$ and $x=0,(\frac 1 2 )^{\frac 1 n}$ are the roots of the derivative. I found that the second derivative is negative in the second point. then $\sup=1/4$ and the function does not converge uniformally?

Comment: You should edit your title for it to show $x^{2n}$.

Comment: I fixed the title. thank you.

Comment: This is fine. In fact, you need only point out that the pointwise limit is the zero function and $f_n((1/2)^{1/n})=1/4$ for all $n$ (no need to show this in fact gives the sup).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose an arbitrarily large *odd* value of $n$.  There exists some $0<x<1$ such that $x^n>\dfrac 12$.

Then $$\begin{array}{rl}f_n(-x) &= (-x)^n - (-x)^{2n}
\\ &= -\left(x^n + x^2n\right) \\ &\leq -\frac 34 \end{array}$$

So $f_n$ does not converge uniformly on $(-1,1]$.

Answer (score 1):

$f$ doesn't converge uniformly in $(-1,1]$ since
$$\lim_{x\to-1}\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=0\neq\lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{x\to-1}f_n(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}(-1)^n-1$$

Answer (score 0):

An idea: say for $\,n>2\,$

$$f_n(x)=x^n-x^{2n}\implies f'_n(x)=nx^{n-1}-2nx^{2n-1}=nx^{n-1}\left(1-2x^{n}\right)=0\iff$$

$$x=0\,,\,\frac1{\sqrt[n]2}$$

$$f_n''(x)=n(n-1)x^{n-2}-2n(2n-1)x^{2n-2}\implies\begin{cases}f''(0)=0\\{}\\f''\left(\frac1{\sqrt[n]2}\right)=\frac{n\sqrt[n]4}4\left(-2n\right)<0\end{cases}\;\implies$$

$$\implies\text{at}\;\;\left(x=\frac1{\sqrt[n]2}\;,\;y=f_n\left(\frac1{\sqrt[n]2}\right)=-\frac14\right)\;\text{we have a maximum for}\;\;f_n(x)\;,\;\forall\,n>2 .$$

And from here it follows at once that since $\,\displaystyle{f(x):=0=\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)}\;$ , then

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{n}|f_n(x)-f(x)|=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac14=\frac14$$

and thus the convergence isn't uniform.

Comment: I think that for x=1, $f_n(x)=1^n-1^{2n}=0\to 0$. Isn't it?

Comment: Oops! you're right, I misread $\,f_n(x)\,$ ...thanks.

Comment: @theOrthanormalBeginner, I edited my answer and you can check it now.

Comment: That was the way I used which described in the main thread. thanks anyway